# List View Array from Database

Tags: android, android-listview

I have retrieved data and successfully shown it in text view. 
What do I have to modify in my code to make it look like a list view?
And also how do modify my listview programatically(adding size and padding)?

Here is a part of my DBclass in selecting the items that I've displayed

```
    getFAData() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      String [] columns = new String[]{Row_Name};
      Cursor c = ourDB.query(db_Table, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
      String res = "";

      int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(Row_Name);
      //int iDesc = c.getColumnIndex(Row_Desc);
      //int iID = c.getColumnIndex(Row_id);

      for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())
      {
        res = res + c.getString(iRow) + "\n";
      }
      return res;
    }
```

And here is the class file:

```
    public class FirstAid extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.firstaid);
        displayresult();
    }

    public void displayresult (){
        TextView tvFa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvFA);
        tvFa.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        DbHelper tblFa = new DbHelper(this);
        tblFa.open();
        String result = tblFa.getFAData();
        tblFa.close();

        tvFa.setText(result);
    }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried the one that populates the whole screen with the data. i just followed some tutorials on the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create ArrayList int the get data function of database

```
public ArrayList<String> getFAData() {
    ArrayList<String> comments = new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor c = ourDB.query(db_Table, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(Row_Name);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {          
        comments.add(c.getString(iRow ));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // Make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();
    return comments;
}
```

in your activity retrieve data like this.

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
array = tblFa.getFAData();
```

Comment: sir can you explain more what to add in my activity? i am really getting confused how to show the result in listview. do i have have to change to activity to extends ListActivity?

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement a method in your dbhelper class like this

```
 public List<String> selectAll_data() {
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

      Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME_2, new String[] { "str" },
              null , null, null, null, null);

      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         do {
                list.add(cursor.getString(0));                  

           } while (cursor.moveToNext());
      }
      if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
         cursor.close();
      }

      return list;
   }
```

Now in your activity

```
 List<String> events = dh.selectAll_data(); 
 String[] arr = new String[events.size()];      
 arr = events.toArray(arr);

 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

 // Assign adapter to ListView
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

If you want to see a real time example check this [url](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/)

Comment: list.add(cursor.getString(0)); does the zero here refer to the column index on my table?

Comment: its the index of the string we are retrieved from the database. here we are retrieving only one field str, so i use 0 only

Comment: Thanks to both of you, its now working. But i got another problem, i need to click the list that i populate on the list view send send an information on the next activity, but it has about 300 entries. I really have no idea what to do next.

Comment: implement setOnItemClickListener for listview and send clicked item as extra through intent. check this http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1351248

Comment: aouch. a cursorAdapter would be much more efficient